# R, leaflet package, Passing a character vector of HTML tags to popups?

Tags: html, r, url, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to emulate the first example on https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html but with a vector of html tags rather than one.

Example on https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/popups.html:

> content

```
[1] "<b><a href='http://www.samurainoodle.com'>Samurai Noodle</a></b><br/>606 5th Ave. S<br/>Seattle, WA 98138"
```

Mine:

> bird$html[1]

```
[1] "<a href=‘https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Gadwall/id’>more info</a>"
```

However, when I pass the code to leaflet popup, the more info hyperlink displays and links to a not found page rather than the url. Do i have to add any special characters to the HTML tag (e.g. slashes or quotations)? Any thoughts?

```
leaflet () %>%
      addTiles(urlTemplate = base_map, attribution = mb_attribution)%>%
      addMarkers(bird$lon, bird$lat, 
                 popup=paste(sep="","<b>", bird$Common.Name,"</b>",
                             "<br/>","<font size=2 color=#045FB4>","Scientific Name: ","</font>" ,bird$Scientific.Name,
                             "<br/>","<font size=2 color=#045FB4>","Number Observed: ","</font>", bird$Count,
                             "<br/>","<font size=2 color=#045FB4>","Location: ","</font>", bird$Location,
                             "<br/>","<font size=2 color=#045FB4>","Region: ","</font>", bird$Area,
                             "<br/>","<font size=2 color=#045FB4>", "Date: ", "</font>", bird$Date,
                             "<br/>", bird$html),
                 clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
      addPopups(bird$lon, bird$lat, bird$html, options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)
      )
```

Comment: Also maybe look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173336/how-to-display-advanced-customed-popups-for-leaflet-in-shiny) for even more elaborate popups.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using a wrong quotation string. `’` instead of `'`. It works for me if I reverse the quote string as so:

```
'<a href="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Gadwall/id">more info</a>'
```

Double quotes to escape the URL.