# How to add a downloadButton in a popup?

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I'm currently developing an R Shiny application where I'm mapping services providers on a map and when I click on a specific marker I have a popup with additional information and I would like to include a downloadButton in that popup. Unfortunately when I'm calling the downloadHandler it doesn't work and I'm downloading a html file called qwe_download.html. But if I put the downloadButton outside the popup (i.e. in the ui) then it works. Is it possible to use a downloadButton inside a leaflet popup?

I can't share the original code as it is quite sensitive but you can find below what I'm trying to achieve.

```
library('leaflet')
library('shinydashboard')



id <- c(1, 2, 3)
lat <- c(10.01, 10.6, 10.3)
long <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
name <- c('test1', ' test2', 'test3')
test <- data_frame(id, lat, long, name)


#User interface

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Title', titleWidth = 900)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 300)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
  leafletOutput("map")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker=NULL)  
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    mymap <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(data = test, lng = long, lat = lat, layerId = id,
                 popup = paste0(
                   "<div>",
                   "<h3>",
                   "Name:&nbsp;",
                   test$name,
                   downloadButton(outputId = "dlData",label =  "Download Details"),
                   "</div>"))
    
    observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
      print("observed map_marker_click")
      data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click
      print(data$clickedMarker)
      x <- filter(test, id == data$clickedMarker$id)
      view(x)})
    
    data_react <- reactive({
      data_table <- filter(test, test$id == data$clickedMarker$id)
    })
    
    
    
    
    output$dlData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "dataset.csv",
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data_react(), file)
      }
    )
    
   
    
    mymap
  })
  
}


# Run app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that the observeEvent block was just there for me to check if my code was filtering the right selection.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the downloadButtons yourself after placing them in the popup.

Please see [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shiny-bindall/14489/2) related answer from Joe Cheng.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173336/how-to-display-advanced-customed-popups-for-leaflet-in-shiny) you can find some great answers on how to `bindAll` custom inputs in a leaflet popup.

And this is how to apply those answers regarding your particular requirements:

```
library('leaflet')
library('shinydashboard')

id <- c(1, 2, 3)
lat <- c(10.01, 10.6, 10.3)
long <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
name <- c('test1', ' test2', 'test3')
test <- data.frame(id, lat, long, name)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Title', titleWidth = 900)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 300)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$div(id = "garbage"),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
  leafletOutput("map")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker = NULL)
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    mymap <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        data = test,
        lng = long,
        lat = lat,
        layerId = id,
        popup = sprintf(
          paste0(
            "<div>",
            "<h3>",
            "Name:&nbsp;",
            test$name,
            br(),
            downloadButton(outputId = "dlData%s", label =  "Download Details"),
            "</div>"
          ),
          id
        )
      ) %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(
        'function(el, x) {
              var target = document.querySelector(".leaflet-popup-pane");
            
              var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                  if(mutation.addedNodes.length > 0){
                    Shiny.bindAll(".leaflet-popup-content");
                  }
                  if(mutation.removedNodes.length > 0){
                    var popupNode = mutation.removedNodes[0];
            
                    var garbageCan = document.getElementById("garbage");
                    garbageCan.appendChild(popupNode);
            
                    Shiny.unbindAll("#garbage");
                    garbageCan.innerHTML = "";
                  }
                });
              });
            
              var config = {childList: true};
            
              observer.observe(target, config);
            }'
      )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    print("observed map_marker_click")
    data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click
    print(data$clickedMarker)
    x <- filter(test, id == data$clickedMarker$id)
    })
  
  data_react <- reactive({
    data_table <- filter(test, test$id == data$clickedMarker$id)
  })
  
  lapply(id, function(i) {
    output[[paste0("dlData", i)]] <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "dataset.csv",
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data_react(), file)
      }
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It worked perfectly. I just would like to understand why it worked and what we're doing especially in the `htmlwidgets::onRender` and why we created a garbage `div`.

Comment: The `onRender` / `bindAll` part is described in the answers I linked (quite detailed). The only difference regarding your question was the need to provide a `downloadHandler` for each button.

Answer (score 2):

The download button is not binded to Shiny. You can use the **pointerenter** event to run `Shiny.bindAll()` and the **pointerleave** event to run `Shiny.unbindAll()`:

```
library('leaflet')
library('shinydashboard')
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1, 2, 3)
lat <- c(10.01, 10.6, 10.3)
long <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
name <- c('test1', ' test2', 'test3')
test <- tibble(id, lat, long, name)

js <- "$('body').on('pointerenter', '#dlData', function(){Shiny.bindAll('#dwnld');}).on('pointerleave', '#dlData', function(){Shiny.unbindAll('#dwnld');})"

header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Title', titleWidth = 900)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 300)

body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$script(HTML(js)),
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
  leafletOutput("map")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactiveValues(clickedMarker=NULL)  
  
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    mymap <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(
        data = test, lng = long, lat = lat, layerId = id,
        popup = paste0(
          "<div id='dwnld'>",
          "<h3>",
          "Name:&nbsp;",
          test$name,
          "</h3>",
          downloadButton(
            outputId = "dlData", label = "Download Details"
          ),
          "</div>")) 
    mymap
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
    data$clickedMarker <- input$map_marker_click
  })
  
  data_react <- reactive({
    filter(test, id == data$clickedMarker$id)
  })
  
  output$dlData <- downloadHandler(
    "dataset.csv",
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data_react(), file)
    })

}

# Run app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Stéphane, this is far more readable than @K.Rohde's approach, however, it throws JS errors in the console `Uncaught Duplicate binding for ID dlData` due to the missing unbind as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36418876/9841389).

Comment: By creating 3 downloadButtons, do you mean one per data point? So if my original dataset has 450 data points how would I need to approach this?

Comment: @Nusta in my answer there is a downloadButton and a downloadHandler for each datapoint - see the `lapply` call.

Comment: @Nusta I've just modified my answer. I put the `unbind`  in the download handler. This works. There's no need of multiple download handlers.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent this way only one of the three buttons works - always the first button clicked (In the end I'm also only copying the same downloadHandler to the correct output).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Which three buttons? I tested it yesterday for several cities and it worked.

Comment: If you don't mind I'll edit and share a gif - feel free to remove it.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks. I'm surprised since it worked yesterday. Gonna check again.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Ah yes, it works only if you don't go directly from a city to another one.

Comment: That makes sense - then there are no duplicated buttons.

Comment: Another point which might be not ideal, is the fact that `unbindAll` won't get called if the user opens the popup but doesn't click on the downloadButton.

Comment: @ismirsehregal Please see my answer. I totally changed the method.

Comment: Thats running fine - a good alternative!

Answer (score 1):

To add a summarizing answer, what we need to do:

1. Call `Shiny.[un]bindAll` in the "right" moment.
2. The "right" moment is apparently once the popup is added / removed from the DOM.
3. Non working downloads can happen as a result of re-using the same `id` (unfortunately I could not identify a pattern and I thought that `unbinding` helps, but it does not). Thus, to play it safe creating unique download handlers should avoid this behaviour.

Having said that, the IMHO cleanest option to call `Shiny.bindAll()` is in response to the `popupopen` event:

```r
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      
      mymap <- leaflet() %>%
         addTiles() %>%
         addMarkers(
            data = test, lng = long, lat = lat, layerId = id,
            popup = paste0(
               "<div id='dwnld'>",
               "<h3>",
               "Name:&nbsp;",
               test$name,
               downloadButton(outputId = "dlData",label = "Download Details"),
               "</div>")) 
      mymap %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(HTML("
         function(el, x) {
            this.on('popupopen', function() {
               Shiny.bindAll('#dwnld');
            });
            this.on('popupclose', function() {
               Shiny.unbindAll('#dwnld');
            });
         }"))
   })
```